# How to pass a string variable from servlet to jsp and store the value in another variable?

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I want to pass a string variable from servlet to jsp and store it's value in another variable in jsp.

Here is servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("rep", docbase);
request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Here is my jsp:

```
</script>
        <script type="text/ajavscript">
        var repository = '${rep}';

        </script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {        
          alert('.repository');
            $.ajax({
             url:'ServiceToFetchDocType',
             data: {name:repository},
             type:'post',
             cache:false,
             success: function(response)
             {


             }
            });

        });


        </script>
```

The alert box is showing undefined. I'm not sure if I'm able to pass the value successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var repository = '${rep}' worked. I had to put it inside this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {        
          alert('.repository');
            $.ajax({
             url:'ServiceToFetchDocType',
             data: {name:repository},
             type:'post',
             cache:false,
             success: function(response)
             {


             }
            });

        });


        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change the line from:

```
var repository = '${rep}';
```

to:

```
var repository = '<%=request.getAttribute("rep")%>';
```